# Prevent a category being displayed when using category="{segment_3_category_id}"

Tags: categories, low-seg2cat

Because of the URL schema on a site I'm working on I'm using {segment_x_category_id} (via Low Seg2Cat - http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat) to grab the category ID and pass it to a channel entries loop.

The problem I have is that there are a couple of specific categories which I never want to be navigable using this method. Usually I would exclude them specifically using category="not 1|2|3" but when I also need to pass in the category I want to display that's not going to work... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@derek's answer is good, except that it will match other categories containing the numbers, like `18`.

So, let's improve it using the [contains](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#contains-operator) and the [concatenation](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#string-concatenation-operator) operators, instead of a regex.:

```
{if '/32/15/8/' *= '/'.segment_x_category_id.'/'}
    {redirect="404"}
{/if}
```

I'm using `/` as delimiter, but it could be some different character.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running 2.9, you could use a regular expression conditional to send the visitor to a 404 when trying to browse those categories:

```
{if segment_x_category_id ~ "/32|15|8/"}
    {redirect="404"}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nathan, you can also check [GWcode Categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/documentation) which gives you more flexibility dealing with categories.

Example:

{exp:gwcode_categories channel="abcd" cat_id="{segment_3_category_id}" depth="1|2" style="linear" excl_cat_id="1|3" limit="9" parse="inward"}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}